# Django ORM error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword XXX into field

Tags: django, database

When I typing 
`comds = Purchased.objects.filter(category_id = '1')`,
it thrown a error like this
`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'category_id' into field. Choices are: comd_expire, comd_img_type, comd_name, id, player, player_id, purchase_time, status`,
and my table's fields are:
[image]
my models is:
[image]
I don't know why there has no category and category_id

Comment: Have you tried just `id='1'`

Comment: Show your category model

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Make sure you have saved your `models.py` and restarted the serve so that Django is running the current version of the code. Please post code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: As @Exprator said: its DOUBLE underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
comds = Purchased.objects.filter(category__id =1)
```